# How would I write a SQL query that finds users that have been active in the last few years?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been tasked with creating a list of inactive users from a database. The database has a list of users in one table (users) and a list of the classes those users have signed up for in another (users_classdetails). The users_classdetails page has columns for userID and dateEntered (which is a timestamp). Users has typical data such as id, name, address, phone, and so on.

I need a SQL query that will get me a list of users that haven't signed up for a class in the last three years. I can get a list of users that signed up for classes more than three years ago, but it doesn't take into account if they signed up recently. Whats the best way to go about this?

The users table

```
id, username, firstName, lastName, email, phone, address
```

The users_classdetails

```
id, userID, classID, dateEntered
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many dbms products handle date/time in their own way...)

Comment: Provide us with table structures, sample data and the version of sql you are working on (mysql, sql-server, oracle, ...)

Comment: It's a MySQL database.
users table  has id, username, firstName, lastName, email, phone, address
users_classdetails has id, userID, classID, dateEntered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List users who have no row in users_classdetails with a date more recent than 3 years ago. ANSI SQL style:

```
select * from users u
where NOT exists (select 1 from users_classdetails uc
                  where u.id = uc.userID
                    and dateEntered > current_date - interval'3' year)
```

If the opposite is wanted, i.e. list all users who has been active during the last 3 years, then switch to `EXISTS`.
But the body says not been active, then switch to `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: `not exists`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to agregate results and get max date

```
SELECT s.*
FROM users s
JOIN (select userid, MAX(dateEntered) Max_date from users_classdetails GROUP BY userid) uc
ON s.id = uc.userid
AND uc.Max_date > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR)
```